# Android Mobile Network Socket Implementation Write using extra data

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on a Cellular based Android application that has a very low Data Usage cap.

The app connects to a TCP server socket port and transmits / receives to the server some identification information and diagnostic information.

The problem that I have noticed is that when using the Socket OutputStream to write a particular amount of bytes (to provide an exact example, I am sending a 32 byte array) that my actual TX and RX data usage (as reported by TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() and TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()) show that I used 52 bytes of TX data, and 110 bytes of RX data.

Why does the write use extra TX AND RX data, when I only want it to send the 32 byte array?

Thanks,
Marshall

Answer (score 0):

The increased size is because of the TCP header transmitted along with your data. The size of TCP header is 20 bytes. You can read more details about TCP header [here](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/transmission-control-protocol-tcp-header/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... This would explain the extra TX data, but I don't see how this would create any RX data?